# Tensorflow Issue with Import on Mac M2

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tensorflow

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm attempting to run TensorFlow on my Mac M2 Air but encountering an error that suggests a circular import issue. Below are the steps I've followed for installation:

1. Installed TensorFlow and related packages via pip:

   - `python3 -m pip install tensorflow`
   - `python3 -m pip install tensorflow-hub`
   - `python3 -m pip install tensorflow-text`
   - `python3 -m pip install tensorflow-metal`
   - `python3 -m pip install tensorflow-macos`
2. Installed Miniconda:

   - Downloaded with `curl -O https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-arm64.sh`
   - Installed using `sh Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-arm64.sh`
   - Updated PATH variable: `export PATH="/Users/bri/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"`

```
Python 3.11.5
pip 23.3.1 from /Users/bri/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)
```

However, when I try to import TensorFlow in my script, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bri/code/AI/NLP/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/Users/bri/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v2 import __internal__
  File "/Users/bri/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/__internal__/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v2.__internal__ import autograph
  File "/Users/bri/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/__internal__/autograph/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.autograph.core.ag_ctx import control_status_ctx # line: 34
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/bri/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/core/ag_ctx.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.autograph.utils import ag_logging
  File "/Users/bri/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/utils/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.autograph.utils.context_managers import control_dependency_on_returns
  File "/Users/bri/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/utils/context_managers.py", line 19, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
  File "/Users/bri/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 26, in <module>
    from absl import app
  File "/Users/bri/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 31, in <module>
    import pdb
  File "/Users/bri/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/pdb.py", line 77, in <module>
    import code
  File "/Users/bri/College/S1 - Programming for AI/Modern NLP - week 11 CA/code.py", line 27, in <module>
    import tensorflow_hub as hub
  File "/Users/bri/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/__init__.py", line 85, in <module>
    _ensure_tf_install()
  File "/Users/bri/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/__init__.py", line 74, in _ensure_tf_install
    if (parse_version(tf.__version__) <
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version__' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

This error occurs despite following the installation steps correctly. I am wondering if there is a compatibility issue with the M2 chip or if I've missed a crucial step in the setup.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully run TensorFlow on my Mac M2 Air.

Thank you!

p.s. Install Log of TensorFlow

```
python3 -m pip install tensorflow                                            
Collecting tensorflow
  Downloading tensorflow-2.15.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl.metadata (3.6 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-macos==2.15.0 (from tensorflow)
  Downloading tensorflow_macos-2.15.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl.metadata (4.2 kB)
Collecting absl-py>=1.0.0 (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached absl_py-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.3 kB)
Collecting astunparse>=1.6.0 (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached astunparse-1.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting flatbuffers>=23.5.26 (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached flatbuffers-23.5.26-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (850 bytes)
Collecting gast!=0.5.0,!=0.5.1,!=0.5.2,>=0.2.1 (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached gast-0.5.4-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting google-pasta>=0.1.1 (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached google_pasta-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
Collecting h5py>=2.9.0 (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Downloading h5py-3.10.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl.metadata (2.5 kB)
Collecting libclang>=13.0.0 (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached libclang-16.0.6-py2.py3-none-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl.metadata (5.2 kB)
Collecting ml-dtypes~=0.2.0 (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Downloading ml_dtypes-0.2.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl.metadata (20 kB)
Collecting numpy<2.0.0,>=1.23.5 (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Downloading numpy-1.26.2-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl.metadata (115 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 115.1/115.1 kB 2.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting opt-einsum>=2.3.2 (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached opt_einsum-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /Users/bri/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow) (23.1)
Collecting protobuf!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.20.3 (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached protobuf-4.25.1-cp37-abi3-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl.metadata (541 bytes)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Users/bri/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow) (68.2.2)
Collecting six>=1.12.0 (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting termcolor>=1.1.0 (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached termcolor-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.1 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.6.6 (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.9.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting wrapt<1.15,>=1.11.0 (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Downloading wrapt-1.14.1-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl.metadata (6.7 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem>=0.23.1 (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Downloading tensorflow_io_gcs_filesystem-0.34.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl.metadata (14 kB)
Collecting grpcio<2.0,>=1.24.3 (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Downloading grpcio-1.60.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_10_universal2.whl.metadata (4.0 kB)
Collecting tensorboard<2.16,>=2.15 (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached tensorboard-2.15.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.7 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-estimator<2.16,>=2.15.0 (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached tensorflow_estimator-2.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.3 kB)
Collecting keras<2.16,>=2.15.0 (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached keras-2.15.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.4 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel<1.0,>=0.23.0 in /Users/bri/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from astunparse>=1.6.0->tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow) (0.41.2)
Collecting google-auth<3,>=1.6.3 (from tensorboard<2.16,>=2.15->tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached google_auth-2.25.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.7 kB)
Collecting google-auth-oauthlib<2,>=0.5 (from tensorboard<2.16,>=2.15->tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached google_auth_oauthlib-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.7 kB)
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8 (from tensorboard<2.16,>=2.15->tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached Markdown-3.5.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.1 kB)
Collecting protobuf!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.20.3 (from tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached protobuf-4.23.4-cp37-abi3-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl.metadata (540 bytes)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.21.0 in /Users/bri/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from tensorboard<2.16,>=2.15->tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow) (2.31.0)
Collecting tensorboard-data-server<0.8.0,>=0.7.0 (from tensorboard<2.16,>=2.15->tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached tensorboard_data_server-0.7.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.1 kB)
Collecting werkzeug>=1.0.1 (from tensorboard<2.16,>=2.15->tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached werkzeug-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.1 kB)
Collecting cachetools<6.0,>=2.0.0 (from google-auth<3,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.16,>=2.15->tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached cachetools-5.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.2 kB)
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 (from google-auth<3,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.16,>=2.15->tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached pyasn1_modules-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (181 kB)
Collecting rsa<5,>=3.1.4 (from google-auth<3,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.16,>=2.15->tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached rsa-4.9-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Collecting requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 (from google-auth-oauthlib<2,>=0.5->tensorboard<2.16,>=2.15->tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached requests_oauthlib-1.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<4,>=2 in /Users/bri/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.16,>=2.15->tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow) (2.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /Users/bri/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.16,>=2.15->tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 in /Users/bri/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.16,>=2.15->tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow) (1.26.18)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Users/bri/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.16,>=2.15->tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow) (2023.11.17)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.1.1 (from werkzeug>=1.0.1->tensorboard<2.16,>=2.15->tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.3-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting pyasn1<0.6.0,>=0.4.6 (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<3,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.16,>=2.15->tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached pyasn1-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.6 kB)
Collecting oauthlib>=3.0.0 (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<2,>=0.5->tensorboard<2.16,>=2.15->tensorflow-macos==2.15.0->tensorflow)
  Using cached oauthlib-3.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (151 kB)
Downloading tensorflow-2.15.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl (2.1 kB)
Downloading tensorflow_macos-2.15.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl (208.8 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 208.8/208.8 MB 3.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Using cached absl_py-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (130 kB)
Using cached flatbuffers-23.5.26-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Downloading grpcio-1.60.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_10_universal2.whl (9.7 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 9.7/9.7 MB 4.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading h5py-3.10.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (2.6 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 2.6/2.6 MB 3.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Using cached keras-2.15.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.7 MB)
Using cached libclang-16.0.6-py2.py3-none-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (20.6 MB)
Downloading ml_dtypes-0.2.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl (1.2 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.2/1.2 MB 4.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Downloading numpy-1.26.2-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (14.0 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 14.0/14.0 MB 2.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Using cached tensorboard-2.15.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.5 MB)
Using cached protobuf-4.23.4-cp37-abi3-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl (400 kB)
Using cached tensorflow_estimator-2.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (441 kB)
Downloading tensorflow_io_gcs_filesystem-0.34.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl (1.9 MB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 1.9/1.9 MB 3.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Using cached termcolor-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (7.7 kB)
Using cached typing_extensions-4.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (32 kB)
Downloading wrapt-1.14.1-cp311-cp311-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (36 kB)
Using cached google_auth-2.25.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (184 kB)
Using cached google_auth_oauthlib-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Using cached Markdown-3.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (102 kB)
Using cached tensorboard_data_server-0.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.4 kB)
Using cached werkzeug-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (226 kB)
Using cached cachetools-5.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (9.3 kB)
Downloading MarkupSafe-2.1.3-cp311-cp311-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl (17 kB)
Using cached pyasn1-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (84 kB)
Installing collected packages: libclang, flatbuffers, wrapt, typing-extensions, termcolor, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, tensorflow-estimator, tensorboard-data-server, six, pyasn1, protobuf, oauthlib, numpy, MarkupSafe, markdown, keras, grpcio, gast, cachetools, absl-py, werkzeug, rsa, requests-oauthlib, pyasn1-modules, opt-einsum, ml-dtypes, h5py, google-pasta, astunparse, google-auth, google-auth-oauthlib, tensorboard, tensorflow-macos, tensorflow
Successfully installed MarkupSafe-2.1.3 absl-py-2.0.0 astunparse-1.6.3 cachetools-5.3.2 flatbuffers-23.5.26 gast-0.5.4 google-auth-2.25.2 google-auth-oauthlib-1.2.0 google-pasta-0.2.0 grpcio-1.60.0 h5py-3.10.0 keras-2.15.0 libclang-16.0.6 markdown-3.5.1 ml-dtypes-0.2.0 numpy-1.26.2 oauthlib-3.2.2 opt-einsum-3.3.0 protobuf-4.23.4 pyasn1-0.5.1 pyasn1-modules-0.3.0 requests-oauthlib-1.3.1 rsa-4.9 six-1.16.0 tensorboard-2.15.1 tensorboard-data-server-0.7.2 tensorflow-2.15.0 tensorflow-estimator-2.15.0 tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem-0.34.0 tensorflow-macos-2.15.0 termcolor-2.4.0 typing-extensions-4.9.0 werkzeug-3.0.1 wrapt-1.14.1
```

Comment: Ive been a developer and tech lead for 15 years. I asked a reasonable question and it gets downs voted. I was a defender of Stackoverflow in the face of GPT4/copilot. Im reconsidering my view now! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error is you probably had issues installing tensorflow. Make sure there is no conflicting versions of tensorflow installed.

Comment: I have added the log from installing TensorFlow. How would I know If I had a conflicting version? Thanks